Why are we getting a metabase error when connecting to SQL Server 2016 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 but not on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7?
We noticed a Java application, Metabase, having an error when connecting to SQL Server 2016, and with the same configuration, the issue happens on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9, but not on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. So, we hope to get help to confirm whether it's due to the operating system, and to fix it.
Longer story:
We are testing an upgraded instance of Metabase, and the upgraded components include

Red Hat Enterprise Linux (from v7 to v9) operating system,
Java (from 11 to 21), and
Metabase software (from v0.32.x to the current v0.50.x).

And we noticed the following error in the upgraded instance when connecting to a data source of SQL Server 2016.

"encrypt" property is set to "false" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints. ClientConnectionId:6bf62750-d5c4-49c5-8ada-4253d8b55055

We suspect the error is related to the system behavior of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9, therefore we designed the following simplified test case to support our point:
Test configuration:

Java openjdk v11.0.23
metabase.jar v0.32.5

We start the application by calling command java -jar metabase.jar, so it starts a fresh demonstration instance of Metabase running on local H2 for application database.
Then, we try to add a data source of SQL Server 2016 configured with encryption not required.
Running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, the above test succeeded. However, running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9, it failed with the following log events, notice the timestamp of 12-19 14:58:44:
12-19 14:58:09 DEBUG middleware.log :: GET /api/setup/admin_checklist 200 14 ms (10 DB calls) Jetty threads: 8/50 (3 busy, 5 idle, 0 queued) (48 total active threads)
12-19 14:58:44 INFO metabase.driver :: Initializing driver :sqlserver...
12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG plugins.classloader :: Setting current thread context classloader to shared classloader clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader@1dc9fc0...
12-19 14:58:44 INFO plugins.classloader :: Added URL file:/data/metabase-test/v0.32.5/plugins/sqlserver.metabase-driver.jar to classpath
12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG plugins.init-steps :: Loading plugin namespace metabase.driver.sqlserver...
12-19 14:58:44 INFO metabase.driver :: Registered driver :sqlserver (parents: :sql-jdbc) 
12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG plugins.jdbc-proxy :: Registering JDBC proxy driver for class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver...
Load lazy loading driver :sqlserver took 173 ms
12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG middleware.log :: POST /api/database 400 314 ms (0 DB calls) Jetty threads: 8/50 (3 busy, 4 idle, 0 queued) (45 total active threads)
{:valid false,
 :dbname
 "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: \"Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints\". ClientConnectionId:ca179b99-b3b3-4351-a0de-736b7dc8e765",
 :message
 "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: \"Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints\". ClientConnectionId:ca179b99-b3b3-4351-a0de-736b7dc8e765"}

12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG middleware.log :: GET /api/database 200 5 ms (3 DB calls) Jetty threads: 8/50 (3 busy, 4 idle, 0 queued) (45 total active threads)
12-19 15:00:00 INFO task. Send-pulses :: Sending scheduled pulses...

We wonder if we missed anything with regard to the new operating system, and we highly appreciate any pointers and hints.
Additional Information
About TLS:
The SQL Server 2016 under test does not have SSL certificate installed, and it is configured as "encryption not required".

We checked the Windows host in the context of "SQLServerManager13.msc > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER > Properties". The "Force Encryption" is No, and there is nothing in the "Certificate" tab.
The command openssl s_client outputs the following results:
# openssl s_client -connect <sql-server-hostname>:1433 -showcerts
Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
CONNECTED(00000003)
001EA5D0C87F0000:error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:689:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 309 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---



About SQL Server Version:
With everything the same for running Metabase, we tested adding a data source on SQL Server 2022 instead of 2016, and the test passed on RHEL9.
About the Differences in java.security:
Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149545/java-security-cert-certificateexception-certificates-does-not-conform-to-algori

We retrieved the java.security files from both RHEL7 and RHEL9, then filtered out the comments and blanks to get the net contents. By comparing the two files, we got the differences below.
$ diff java.security.11.rhel7.txt java.security.11.rhel9.txt
12a13,16
> fips.provider.1=SunPKCS11 ${java.home}/conf/security/nss.fips.cfg
> fips.provider.2=SUN
> fips.provider.3=SunEC
> fips.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider SunPKCS11-NSS-FIPS
23a28
> fips.keystore.type=PKCS11
26,28c31
<                sun.reflect.,\
<                org.GNOME.Accessibility.,\
<                org.GNOME.Bonobo.
---
>                sun.reflect.
30,32c33
<                    sun.reflect.,\
<                    org.GNOME.Accessibility.,\
<                    org.GNOME.Bonobo.
---
>                    sun.reflect.
33a35
> security.useSystemPropertiesFile=true
59,60c61,63
< jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
<     DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
---
> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, DTLSv1.0, RC4, DES, \
>     MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
>     ECDH, \
86c89
< jdk.security.caDistrustPolicies=SYMANTEC_TLS
---
> jdk.security.caDistrustPolicies=SYMANTEC_TLS,ENTRUST_TLS



[Edit] your question to include your TLS details

I have added the TLS information, and please let me know if you need more.

Many thanks! So, I added information about the differences in the java.security file between the two RHEL versions of 7 and 9. Please point out if I am still missing some points, appreciated!

openssl s_client won't work because SQLServer doesn't layer something above SSL/TLS (like HTTPS=HTTP over SSL/TLS) instead it wraps SSL/TLS within its own protocol TDS. If you set sysprop javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:trustmanager it should log all details of the attempted handshake, including the cert chain it received and rejected.

The java.security file on RHEL9 no longer supports the old algorithms on our SQL Server 2016, so the best practice should be to upgrade the SQL Server.
